# How to loop data inside array URL from sqlite?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I want to create app to download image from API. The URL is dynamic, from sqlite

this is my code:

```
private URL[] URLS;
ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
String imagesName;
.........
.........
.........

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


// Database
dataBase = new DataBaseHelper(this);
try {
    cursor = dataBase.getImageFiles();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    imagesName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("path"));
    urlList.add(imagesName);
}
}finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

I want to loop data to this code, but I got error `; expected`

```
URLS = new URL[]{
    // is it possible to loop data here other way ?
    // I want to loop data from sqlite here
    // but I got error

    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
        stringToURL(urlList.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to do that ? or any other way to loop data inside array?
Thank you..

Comment: You can make an `ArrayList` that can contain any object. Why not just create something like this `ArrayList<URL> urlList = new ArrayList<>();`? Then you can loop through `for(URL url : urlList){ String s = url.toString(); }`

Comment: @Barns thanks, I try but still not working..

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: @Barns sorry, just download from one url, not multiple url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why the following code would not work...

```
ArrayList<URL> urlList = new ArrayList<>();

private void parseDatabase(){
    dataBase = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.getImageFiles();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String imagesName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("path"));
            URL url = new URL(imagesName);
            urlList.add(url);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

private void iterateOverUrlList(){
    for(URL url : urlList){
        String urlString = url.toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "URL = " + urlString)
    }
}
```

Sure, its generic but if you have more than one row in the database than it would fill the `ArrayList` of `URL` and then with `iterateOverUrlList()` would print them to the console.